# Kaiser Criterion after Rotation

Tags: pca, eigenvalues

Within my PCA, I rotated the solution, so the output would make more sense given the complex structure using a Varimax rotation. However, when I am confirming the number of factors to extract based on the Kaiser Criterion (KC), am I still analyzing the number of Initial Eigenvalues or do we look at the Extraction Sums of Squared Loadings or Rotation Sums of Squared Loadings.

The reason for my question is because I understand SPSS has a default threshold of 1 for KC. But does that apply under the Rotation? As in once a rotation is performed, does one then analyze the new Sums of squared Loadings and check if any are greater than 1, in which case the number greater than 1 are the number of components to be retained?

I am using SPSS.